# Calls between static methods - will that foil thread safety?

Tags: c#, static, thread-safety

In a public static class I have the following local method:

```
private static int GetMaxFromList(IEnumerable<int> list)
    {
        var result = 0;

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            if (i > result) result = i;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This method is called by some of the public methods within the class (example):

```
public static bool IsIntegrityOfDataSetGood(DataSet dataSet, KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> tableAndColumnIndexes)
    {
        return IsIntegrityOfDataSetGood(dataSet, tableAndColumnIndexes.Key) &&
               dataSet.Tables[tableAndColumnIndexes.Key].Columns.Count > GetMaxFromList(tableAndColumnIndexes.Value);
    }
```

Note that this public method also calls another public method within the class.

The class methods only work with data sent to them through parameters, but I am worried that the calls between the static methods will mess up thread safety. Am I right to worry?

Forgot to mention that this code resides in a .NET 2.0 project.

Comment: Only if the static methods access (static) objects/methods that are not thread-safe, but as you mention, you method only uses the list that is provided to it. A problem could arise if the `list` that is provided (`tableAndColumnIndexes.Value`) is changed during the call.

Comment: btw, see also: `tableAndColumnIndexes.Value.Max()` - no need for your `GetMaxFromList` method

Comment: Thread safety is a *global* property of the *entire* program. You can't look at individual methods and decide each of them is threadsafe and conclude that the whole program is threadsafe. You cannot look at individual bricks, discover that none of them are hollow, and conclude that the house made of those bricks will also not be hollow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this will *not* foil your thread-safety.

But whether it really is thread-safe depends on where `tableAndColumnIndexes` comes from and what other Threads have access to it. In other words, it depends on the calling code.

Answer (score 3):

So long as no other threads are changing the `list` sequence, it should be absolutely fine. It doesn't access any shared state - it just uses its parameter. If any other thread *is* modifying the sequence, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`.

It sounds like you may have some misconceptions about thread safety and static methods, but it's hard to tell exactly what they are... you may find Eric Lippert's blog post ["What is this thing you call thread safe?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) useful.

Comment: Thanks, and I think I agree about the misconceptions ;-) About DefaultIfEmpty(), the project runs on .NET 2.0.

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder: Ick - okay. (It's probably worth mentioning that in future questions, btw... although it was only tangential in this case.) I've edited that bit out of my answer.

Comment: I agree, and the LINQ tip was appreciated all the same.